# Inductive half wave rectifier analysis

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier

The following analysis is taken of power electronics book of William Hart

[image][image]

I do not understand the process to pass of first equation to second, solving the derivative of the first equation and rearranging does not add up the accounts.

Comment: The second equation, at lower right, doesn't pass simple dimensional analysis validation. It also doesn't arrive from the first equation at top, either. Probably a mistake in the book.

Comment: _"solving the derivative of the first equation and rearranging does not add up the accounts"_ - What do you get?